# What's the difference between a trap representation and a unspecified value?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

In 3.19.3 p1, C11 says that an unspecified value cannot be a trap representation, but I don't understand what value can be not a trap representation as well as unspecified.

BTW, I also wonder how can the compiler know whether an object representation is a trap representation or not?

Answer (score 4):

It's the difference between control and data.

Unspecified values can result in unexpected values in results (function return, assignments to global variables, etc).  But the normal control flow of your program will still be followed.

Trap representations, on the other hand, can cause control flow that is not described by your use of branching statements (function calls, conditionals, loops, gotos, returns).

A classic example is a signalling NaN in IEEE 754.  Depending on the FPU control word, encountering a signalling NaN can cause immediate transfer to an exception handler (aka software interrupt aka signal).

Comment: So if the value of an automatic variable isn't a trap representation, it's called a unsprcified value. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

**DEFINITIONS OF TERMS**

**Unspecified behavior** — behavior, for a correct program construct and correct data, for which the Standard imposes no requirements.

**Undefined behavior** — behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct, of erroneous data, or of *indeterminately-valued objects*, for which the Standard imposes no requirements.

> During the construction of a const object, if the value of the object
>   or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not
>   obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor’s this pointer,
>   the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified.

```
struct C;
void no_opt(C*);

struct C {
    int c;
    C() : c(0) { no_opt(this); }
};

const C cobj;

void no_opt(C* cptr) {
    int i = cobj.c * 100; // value of cobj.c is unspecified
    cptr->c = 1;
    cout << cobj.c * 100 // value of cobj.c is unspecified
         << ’\n’;
}
```

In the above example there is no uninitialized value and hence no trap representation but the standard does not grantee(specify) its behavior. The compiler in the above example is allowed to do whatever to do with it, i.e., different compiler will give different result.

> The English term is used more or less verbatim: "unspecified" means
>   that the precise semantics are not given by the standard, but the
>   program does not become undefined or ill-formed.
>
> A trap representation is a set of bits which, when interpreted as a
>   value of a specific type, causes undefined behavior. Trap
>   representations are most commonly seen on floating point and pointer
>   values, but in theory, almost any type could have trap
>   representations. An uninitialized object might hold a trap
>   representation. This gives the same behavior as the old rule: access
>   to uninitialized objects produces undefined behavior.

Take the following example :

```
unsigned char a, b;
memcpy(&a, &b, 1);
a -= a;
```

- Here the addresses of `a` and `b` are taken, so their value is just indeterminate.
- Since `unsigned char` never has trap representations that indeterminate value is just unspecified, any value of `unsigned char` could happen.
- At the end `a` must hold the value `0`.

`a` and `b` have unspecified values:

> **3.19.3 unspecified value**
>
> valid value of the relevant type where this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

Comment: Actually, I think the Committee decided during a defect review that the semantics of code like the above were unclear, and decided to explicitly say that observation of an unsigned char value holding Indeterminate Value would leave it holding Indeterminate Value, rather than turn it into an Unspecified Value.  Consequently, if `unsigned char` is 8 bits, the value of a-a could be anything from -255 to +255, and after the above `a` could hold any value. I think the result of the expression would be Unspecified rather than Indeterminate, but I'm not sure about that.